# Ways of initialising a string in c++

Tags: c++

what is the difference between initializing the string in the following ways?

```
string s = "Hello World";
```

and

```
string s[] = {"Hello World"};
```

From what i understand the former is a class? And the latter an array? Moreover, are there any other ways apart from these two?

Comment: The title has nothing to do with the content of the question...

Comment: `std::string s[]` - is an array of strings. The two lines are not equivalent.

Comment: I think you meant std::string s = "hello world"; and std::string s { "hello world" }; the latter is brace initializer and an encouraged way in modern C++. The first one will trigger move assignment (if available) the latter one will use appropriate constructor.

Answer (score 6):

In the first example, you define one object of class `string`.
In the second, you declare an array of strings of undefined length (computed by compiler, based on how many objects you define in the initializer list) and you initialize one `string` object with "Hello World." So You create an array of size 1.

```
string s = "Hello World";
string s2[] = {"Hello World"};
```

After this, `s` and `s2[0]` contains strings with identical characters in them.

Comment: is string s[] = {"Hello World"} the same as char* s = "Hellow World" and char s[] = {"Hello World"}?

Comment: @mur It is not. You should read some beginner info about std::string and how it differs from C strings (char* and const char*)

Answer (score 1):

Statement

```
string s = "Hello World";
```

creates an object of class `std::string` from a string literal, while

```
string s[] = {"Hello World"};
```

creates an array (of length 1) of `std::string` objects.

Other ways to construct a string from a string literal are the following:

```
string s("Hello World"); // using old style constructor call
string s {"Hello World"}; // using new brace initializer (preffered way)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

    // C-style string; considered "deprecated", better use string class
    char *s1 = "Hello World";
    cout << s1 << endl;

    // Copy constructors
    string s2 = "Hellow World";
    cout << s2 << endl;

    string s3("Hello World");
    cout << s3 << endl;

    string s4{"Hello World"}; // C++11, recommended
    cout << s4 << endl;

    // Move constructor; C++11
    string s5 = move("Hello World");
    cout << s5 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This defines an **array of type `string`** and contains exactly one `string` element representing the *Hello World* character sequence.

```
string s[] = {"Hello World"}; // array of string; not a string by itself
```